# jquery: Get number of option in multi select

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I'd like to know how can i have the number of option in multi select.
I try this but length is always 0

```
var perfDecl = $("input[title='Perf Decl selected values'] option");
            alert(perfDecl.val());
            alert(perfDecl.length);
```

I did a mistake. Here is the correct one to get option on select

```
var perfDecl = $("SELECT[title='Perf Decl selected values'] option");
```

Comment: Can you show us your html? Are you using an input or select?

Comment: An `<input>` element has no `<option>`s

Comment: thanks with your comment i did a mistake. it was select in place of input

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to know the number of elements "option" into a "select":

https://jsfiddle.net/qfbmqwus/1/

```
<select title='test'>
    <option />
    <option />
</select>

alert($('select[test=\'test\'] > option').length) // alerts 2
```